# When onRejected in axios.interceptors.request.use will be triggered?

Tags: vue.js, axios, axios-retry

I've been trying for two hours to figure out when `onRejected` will work in `axios.interceptors.request.use`. I searched everywhere, but I didn't find an answer. I want to handle all cases where the request fails. Basically my goal is to find out if the request will be repeated if it is rejected in `axios.interceptors.request.use`. I'm using `axios-retry`. I did my best to simulate this state, but it didn't work.

The documentation says (axios-retry)

> retry on Network Error & 5xx responses

Please, can you help me? Thank you in advance.

```
import axios from "axios";
import store from './store/index';
import router from "./router";
import axiosRetry from "axios-retry";

export const HTTP = axios.create({
    baseURL: '/api/'
});

HTTP.defaults.showLoader = true;

HTTP.interceptors.request.use(
    request => {
        store.commit('loader_x/PENDING');
        const token = store.getters["auth_x/token"];

        if (token) {
            request.headers["Authorization"] = token;
        }

        // return false;
        // throw new Error('Request ERROR');

        return request;
    },
    error => {
        console.log('ERROR REQUEST');
        store.commit('loader_x/DONE');
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);
HTTP.interceptors.response.use(
    response => {
        store.commit('loader_x/DONE');
        return response;
    },
    error => {
        console.log('RESPONSE ERROR');

        if ('sub_code' in error.response.data) {
            switch (error.response.data.sub_code) {
                case 403:
                    HTTP.post('refresh-token')
                        .then(res => {
                            const authToken = res.data.token_type + ' ' + res.data.access_token;
                            store.commit('auth_x/REFRESH_TOKEN', authToken);
                            error.config.headers['Authorization'] = authToken;
                            return HTTP(error.config);
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                            store.commit('auth_x/LOGOUT');
                            router.push('login').then(() => {
                                store.commit('snackbar_x/SHOW_MESSAGE', { content: err.response.data.message, color: 'info' });
                            });
                        });
                    break;
                case 410:
                    store.commit('auth_x/SET_SUBSCRIBED_STATUS', false);
                    router.push('subscription').then(() => {
                        store.commit('snackbar_x/SHOW_MESSAGE', { content: error.response.data.message, color: 'info' });
                    });
                    break;
            }
        }

        store.commit('loader_x/DONE');
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);

const retryDelay = (retryNumber = 0) => {
    const seconds = Math.pow(2, retryNumber) * 1000;
    const randomMs = 1000 * Math.random();
    if (retryNumber === 3)
    return seconds + randomMs;
};

axiosRetry(HTTP, {
    retries: 3,
    retryDelay,
    // retry on Network Error & 5xx responses
    retryCondition: axiosRetry.isRetryableError,
});
```